# What is the proper pattern serially chaining do-try-catch control flow?

Tags: swift, swift3, exception

I'm looking for a pattern to handle code that looks like this in pseudocode:

```
do:
   try planA()
catch LikelyError e:
   try planB()
catch Error e:
   print ("we're hosed, there is no planC()")
```

In swift, putting a try- in the catch {} block does not work as shown above, instead it appears that it needs to be nested into its own do {} block. This is what that looks like:

```
enum ForeseenError : Error {
   case likelyProblem
   case unlikelyProblem
}

func planA () throws {
   print ("planA")
   throw ForeseenErrors.likelyProblem
}

func planB () throws {
   print ("planB")
   throw ForeseenErrors.unlikelyProblem
}

print ("Hello")
do {
   try planA()
}
catch let error as ForeseenError {
   print ("catch problem, trying planB")
   do {
      try planB()
   }
   catch let error {
      print ("Unrecoverable error from planB")

      /* if i had a planC() that potentially throws, then i'd
      have to put it here in yet another nested do-try-catch 
      control flow structure */

   }
}
catch let error {
   print ("Unrecoverable error from planA")
}

print ("EOM")
```

This feels like an anti-pattern to me, as it requires arbitrarily deep nesting to handle more alternatives. Further, while I might want different handlers for the unrecoverable error from different depths in the sequence of attempts, in general it would make more sense to catch all of them in a final catch block.

So community, what can be done about the logic described above?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own chainable type with a custom `.catch` operation to solve this problem, and create an instance with your own try-like function called `attempt` as in the following:

```swift
class ChainableResult {
    let error: Error? // could also use Result<T, Error> in a generics setting
    
    init(error: Error?) {
        self.error = error
    }
}

func attempt(_ body: () throws -> ()) -> ChainableResult {
    do {
        try body()
        return ChainableResult(error: nil)
    } catch {
        return ChainableResult(error: error)
    }
}

extension ChainableResult {
    
    @discardableResult // <- dangerous
    func `catch`(_ body: (Error) throws -> ()) -> ChainableResult {
        if let originalError = self.error {
            do {
                try body(originalError)
                return ChainableResult(error: originalError)
            } catch {
                let newError = error
                return ChainableResult(error: newError)
            }
        } else {
            return ChainableResult(error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use these constructions like the following:

```swift
attempt {
    try planA()
}.catch {
    err in
    try planB()
}.catch {
    err in
    print("I give up")
}
```

I comment-marked the `@discardableResult` as dangerous because it allows you to write chains in which the final catch operation can throw, in which case the thrown error would go unhandled and ignored.

Ultimately, I ended up writing my own [library for this](https://github.com/async-plus/async-plus). It guards against the dangerous situations like the one I mention, and works with async function bodies as well. The example usage snippet I gave above can be copied verbatim and compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently this seems to be a "developer friendly" pattern from apple. This is still there in the new swift 4 document
[image]

However, if you just want to catch all exceptions at once and find out what exception it is, you can use this hacky way

```
do {
    try planA()
}
catch let error {
    if error as! YourViewController.ForeseenError == ForeseenError.likelyProblem {
        print("1")
    }else{
        print("2")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the developer doc cited really addresses this pattern, the one in which successive error handling resolutions throw their own exceptions in a sequential try-catch-try-catch-giveup fasion.

Comment: @Fooberman You mean the method I provided to catch everything at once? Yes apple doesn't address this because they encourage you to use their official sequential fashion. I'm just providing you this method if you really want to catch all exception at once. Hope that helps.